# Transposing columns and values to a key column Microsoft Access

Tags: microsoft-access

Is there a way I can transpose the data in the format example below. I can export and make it work in Excel but I would really like to be able to automate it in my database.

Example:

Table Format

```
Item      Part A     Part B      Part C
—————————————-
Aaaa        1          2            3
Bbbb     Null          5            6
Cccc        1          2          Null
Dddd        4         Null          6
```

Desired Output from Query

```
   
Item            Part        Qty 
————————————
Aaaa            Part A      1   
Aaaa            Part B      2   
Aaaa            Part C      3   
Bbbb            Part A      
Bbbb            Part B      5   
Bbbb            Part C      6   
Cccc            Part A      1   
Cccc            Part B      2   
Cccc            Part C      
Dddd            Part A      4   
Dddd            Part B      
Dddd            Part C      6
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the SQL used in Access, but in standard SQL this would look similar to:

```
select Item, 'Part A', PartA
from Table
union
select Item, 'Part B', PartB
from Table
union
select Item, 'Part C', PartC
from Table
order by 1,2
```

Comment: Thanks Harry, I will give that a shot.   Is their a limit to how many columns can be tranposed in a union query?  The table in reference has 62 part columns with roughly 50 rows of “items”.

Comment: Hard to say, but if you hit any limits, just use intermediate tables to break it down to manageable pieces.